# Law of conservation of momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, projectile, drag

A meteorite burns up in the atmosphere before it reaches the Earth's surface. What happens to its momentum?
What force does the earth's atmosphere produce so the final momentum becomes 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What force does the earth's atmosphere produce so the final momentum
> becomes 0?

The short answer is the final momentum of the meteorite is not zero because it still has momentum in the form of the motion of its gaseous products of combustion, plus any remaining particulate matter.

However its momentum is not *conserved* because it is exposed to the external forces of air drag and gravity.  Momentum is only conserved for an isolated system. So if you consider the meteorite alone as the system, then momentum is not conserved, because it is not isolated from the air drag and gravitational forces.

If you consider the *combination* of meteorite, atmospheric air, and the Earth as the system, then momentum is conserved because the air drag and gravitational forces are now internal to the system. Then the initial total momentum of the solid meteor, atmospheric air molecules and the Earth will equal the final total momentum of the meteorite combustion products, atmospheric air molecules, and the Earth.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot @Bob D the first line only of your answer cleared my doubt

Answer (score 2):

The momentum gets transferred to the atmosphere that stops/burns the meteorite and eventually to the entire planet Earth. The main force involved is the air drag (type of friction).

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is conserved only when net external force acting on the system is zero. However when the meteorite(system, here) moves through the atmosphere it experiences drag forces (and gravity would also count as an external force, strictly speaking), there's no reason for it's momentum to be conserved.
\begin{equation*}
\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}\Rightarrow \text{if  } \vec{F}=\vec{0},\quad \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=\vec{0},\quad \therefore \vec{p}=constant
\end{equation*}

if you consider meteorite+atmosphere as the system, the drag forces are now internal forces and not external. However the momentum of the system would still not be conserved as gravity (an external force) is acting. Consider Earth+meteorite as the system and now you can safely apply conservation of linear momentum (ignoring the effects of gravity of other heavenly bodies).

edit: made the answer more to the point, previously the language was a little sketchy. Thanks to @hft for the discussion.

Comment: "Conservation of Energy would've been a different story. Law of conservation of energy comes without conditions: it must always hold true..." Not sure why you think energy is somehow "more conserved" than momentum. Each is conserved under the appropriate conditions. Momentum is conserved due to spatial translation invariance. Energy is conserved due to time translation invariance. Explicit time dependence in the Hamiltonian or Lagrangian (e.g., due to moving constraints, time-dep potentials, etc) can cause $dE/dt \neq 0$.

Comment: @hft Of course energy can flow in and out depending on what you consider a system. I was just pointing out that the case of energy is more thought provoking than the momentum one, in the case OP mentioned.

Comment: Momentum can also "flow in and out depending on what you consider a system." Whether or not energy or momentum is "more thought provoking" than the other seems like a matter of opinion.

Comment: I never said otherwise

Comment: I'll try to word this answer more precisely, thank you for the comments.

Comment: @aman Thanks alot Finally some Calculus meaning added to my answer